# How to group columns by label in a histogram using a panda DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, graphics, histogram

I have a panda dataframe called `language` consisting of two columns:

```
    lang          level
0      english         2
1      spanish         2 
2      spanish         1
3      english         1
4      english         3
5      spanish         2
6      spanish         1
7      spanish         3
```

I would like to represent it in a histogram group by the categorical value language in such a way that in the same plot I have 2 groups -one for each language- with as many bar as many labels I have in the level column (3 in this case).

So far I have tried the following by previously categorizaing `lang` getting a label of `1` to `english` and of `2` to `spanish`:

```
language.hist(by=language['lang'])
```

With what I obtained the following graph which is not what I want.[image]

Ideally I would like a graph similar to this where the `LetterGrade` would be `language` and the legend would refer to the `level` variable.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using :

```
pd.crosstab(df.lang,df.level).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]